# Select column matching pattern then keep only rows that match other vector values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, pattern-matching

I want to select the columns in `DT1` that match the pattern `flux` then keep only rows that have values similar to those in a predefined vector `vec1`

**Sample Data**

```
library(data.table)

DT1 <- structure(list(flux_1 = c(1, 6, 2, 9, 5),
                  FileName = c("prac_1", "prac_2", "prac_3", "prac_4", "prac_5")), 
             .Names = c("flux_1", "FileName"), 
             class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
             row.names = c(NA, -5L))
DT1

    flux_1 FileName
1:      1   prac_1
2:      6   prac_2
3:      2   prac_3
4:      9   prac_4
5:      5   prac_5

vec1 <- c(6, 2)
```

The following code works but I need to explicitly specify `flux_1`.

```
DT1[ flux_1 %in% vec1]

   flux_1 FileName
1:      6   prac_2
2:      2   prac_3
```

I was thinking about something like this but it didn't work

```
DT1[, .SD, .SDcols = names(DT1) %like% "flux"] %>% 
  .[. %in% vec1]

Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: flux_1
```

Any suggestion is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `get` to return the value of the column after `grep`

```
DT1[get(grep('flux', names(DT1), value = TRUE)) %in% vec1 ]
#  flux_1 FileName
#1:      6   prac_2
#2:      2   prac_3
```

---

Or if we use the `.SDcols` route, extract the `.SD` as a `vector` do the comparison and subset the dataset

```
DT1[DT1[, .SD[[1]] %in% vec1, .SDcols = grep('flux', names(DT1))]]
```

Similar option can be used with `%like%`

```
DT1[DT1[, .SD[[1]] %in% vec1, .SDcols = names(DT1) %like% "flux"]]
```

---

Regarding the OP's approach

```
DT1[, .SD, .SDcols = names(DT1) %like% "flux"]
#   flux_1
#1:      1
#2:      6
#3:      2
#4:      9
#5:      5
```

returns a `data.table` with a single column.  By chaining, we need to extract the 'flux_1' column

```
DT1[, .SD, .SDcols = names(DT1) %like% "flux"] %>% 
        .[[1]] %in% vec1 %>%
        magrittr::extract(DT1, .)
#   flux_1 FileName
#1:      6   prac_2
#2:      2   prac_3
```

Comment: That was lightning fast! Thanks for the help!

Comment: It keeps getting better. Thanks again!